# How do I save an object with a nested array to Firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I've got the following object and like to save it to Firestore.

```json
{
  "group": [{
      "back": "value",
      "tStamp": {
        "seconds": 1574944200,
        "nanoseconds": 0
      },
      "examples": [{
        "answer": "some text",
        "example": "some more text"
      }, {
        "answer": "some text",
        "example": "some more text"
      }],
      "front": "value"
    },
    {
      "back": "value",
      "tStamp": {
        "seconds": 1575148500,
        "nanoseconds": 0
      },
      "front": "value"
    },
    {
      "back": "value",
      "tStamp": {
        "seconds": 1577831400,
        "nanoseconds": 0
      },
      "front": "value"
    },
  ]
}
```

Trying to save it with `db.collection('cardsb').add(object)` results in an error:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined"

What I a looking for is a way to store the data as described above (an object with nested arrays) into firestore. I am able to store it manually in Firestore. see below:

[image]

This is how the object is generated:

```
cons () {
  const nbrGroups = this.cards.length
  for (let i = 0; i < nbrGroups; i++) {
    var object = []
    const nbrItems = this.cards[i].group.length
    for (let item = 0; item < nbrItems; item++) {
      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inFront, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inBack, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inAnswer, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inExample')
      const examples = []
      if (inputs.length !== 2) {
        for (let i = 2; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          examples.push({ answer: inputs[i + 1].value, example: inputs[i].value })
          i++
        }
        object.push({
          back: inputs[1].value,
          delayed_till: this.cards[i].group[item].delayed_till,
          examples,
          front: inputs[0].value
        })
      } else {
        object.push({
          back: inputs[1].value,
          delayed_till: this.cards[i].group[item].delayed_till,
          front: inputs[0].value
        })
      }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ group: object }))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(object) === JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].group))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].group))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].id))

    db.collection('cardsb').add({ group: object })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show all the code the reproduces the problem?  We need to be able to see exactly how you're building `object`.  The error message is telling you that something inside that object has the value `undefined`, which Firestore will not accept.

Comment: @Doug I updated my question

Comment: There's still not enough information here.  We need to be able to see all the source data as well, which means `this.cards`.  I think you're just going to have to debug this by looking for where you code might be putting `undefined`  in a value somewhere.  If you want help with that, you're going to have to provide a MCVE that anyone can use the duplicate the specific issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If that was the case how is it that the following logs the data correctly to the console `console.log(JSON.stringify({ group: object }))` but the following produces an error `db.collection('cardsb').add({ group: object })`

Comment: console.log doesn't care if some data is undefined.  Firestore will not accept it.

Comment: Thanks Doug, That helped to search in the right direction!

Comment: I am not sure if it changes anything but have you tried adding object into group and then just send the group? `db.collection('cardsb').add(group);`

Comment: @MK01111000 can i ask why do you log this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(object) === JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].group))`? What do you expect?